# Working code to search within dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Someone helped me with this earlier, but there is one problem and I already closed that question.  I do not want to use `JQuery`. The following code works, it allows you to search a dropdown menu:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function searchSel() 
    {
      var input = document.getElementById('realtxt').value.toLowerCase(),
          len = input.length,
          output = document.getElementById('realitems').options;
      for(var i=0; i<output.length; i++)
        if (output[i].text.toLowerCase().slice(0, len) == input)
          output[i].selected = true;
      if (input == '')
        output[0].selected = true;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      search <input type="text" id="realtxt" onkeyup="searchSel()">
      <select id="realitems">
        <option value="">select...</option>
        <option value="1">Power hungry</option>
        <option value="2">Super man</option>
        <option value="3">Hyperactive</option>
        <option value="4">Bored</option>
        <option value="5">Human</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here is the problem.**

It is only limited to the matching first letters of the first word.  So if you typed in `Super` for Super Man, it would work.  But if you typing with `Man` it will not show. Is there a way to make it match the whole string for a matching value?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created a fiddle please check.
http://jsfiddle.net/wLzs4/3/

I have used the indexOf javascript function for your case.

```
function searchSel() 
    {
      var input = document.getElementById('realtxt').value.toLowerCase();

          len = input.length;
          output = document.getElementById('realitems').options;
      for(var i=0; i<output.length; i++)
          if (output[i].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) != -1 ){
          output[i].selected = true;
              break;
          }
      if (input == '')
        output[0].selected = true;
    }
```